# Type Hinting for variable with inherited classes as value

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy

I have doubts about the pythonic way to do something like this:

```
from my_package import A, B

class Main:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        self._var1: Union[A, B]
    
    def set_values(self, value: str) -> None:
    """ Sets the values """
        self._var1.function_caller(value)

class First(Main):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        self._var1 = A()
        # Super Constructor
        Main.__init__(self)

class Second(Main):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        self._var1 = B()
        # Super Constructor
        Main.__init__(self)
```

And then in my main program:

```
import First, Second

my_class = First() if arg['value'] == 'first' else Second()
my_class.set_values('test')
```

This way, MyPy does not show any error but PyCharm gives me the following:

```
Unresolved attribute reference '_var1' for class 'Main'
```

How this situation should be approached in a correct and pythonic way?

Comment: move this: `self._var1: Union[A, B]` out of the `__init__` method and into the top level of the class def of `Main`

Comment: also, generally you should do `super().__init__()` instead of `Main.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```py
from my_package import A, B

class Main:
    _var1: Union[A, B]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        pass
    
    def set_values(self, value: str) -> None:
    """ Sets the values """
        self._var1.function_caller(value)
```

To improve the code further you may consider making `Main` an Abstract Base Class, since it is clearly not meant to be instantiated itself (`_var1` will not be set), and is there to act as a common base for your 'real' classes `First` and `Second`.

```py
from abc import ABC

from my_package import A, B

class Main(ABC):
    _var1: Union[A, B]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        pass
    
    def set_values(self, value: str) -> None:
    """ Sets the values """
        self._var1.function_caller(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to Anentropic's answer. With this variant you cannot "forget" to assign the required attribute. The other answer effectively tells PyCharm: "this class has this attribute" even if it is not provided at runtime.

```
class Main:
    # pass the value via constructor
    def __init__(self, var: Union[A, B]) -> None:
        self._var1 = var

    def set_values(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._var1.function_caller(value)


class First(Main):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # don't set the value but delegate to the base class
        Main.__init__(self, A())


class Second(Main):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # don't set the value but delegate to the base class
        Main.__init__(self, B())
```

Neither mypy nor PyCharm complain here and you cannot forget to set the attribute if you add another sub class.